# network: failed to parse Kubernetes args: pod does not have label vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address

Tags: windows, kubernetes, amazon-eks

**What I try to do:**
EKS with both Linux and Windows (2019) nodes, nginx pod on Linux should access IIS pod on Windows.

**The issue:**
The Windows pods don't start.

**Log:**

```
E0526 10:59:31.963644    4392 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod b35e92cc-7fa2-11e9-b07b-0ac0c740dc70 ("phoenix-57b76c578c-cczs2_kaltura(b35e92cc-7fa2-11e9-b07b-0ac0c740dc70)"), skipping: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "b35e92cc-7fa2-11e9-b07b-0ac0c740dc70" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"phoenix-57b76c578c-cczs2_kaltura\" network: failed to parse Kubernetes args: pod does not have label vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address"
I0526 10:59:37.049583    5020 proxier.go:117] Hns Endpoint resource, {"ID":"9638A3AE-DCB9-4F85-B682-9D2879E09D98","Name":"Ethernet","VirtualNetwork":"82363D68-76A8-4225-8EFC-76F179330CC1","VirtualNetworkName":"vpcbr0a05d9b85b68","Policies":[{"Type":"L2Driver"}],"MacAddress":"00:11:22:33:44:55","IPAddress":"172.31.32.190","PrefixLength":20,"IsRemoteEndpoint":true}
I0526 10:59:37.051589    5020 proxier.go:117] Hns Endpoint resource, {"ID":"8A4C02B1-537B-4650-ADC5-BA24598E3ABA","Name":"Ethernet","VirtualNetwork":"82363D68-76A8-4225-8EFC-76F179330CC1","VirtualNetworkName":"vpcbr0a05d9b85b68","Policies":[{"Type":"L2Driver"}],"MacAddress":"00:11:22:33:44:55","IPAddress":"172.31.36.90","PrefixLength":20,"IsRemoteEndpoint":true}
E0526 10:59:37.064582    5020 proxier.go:1034] Policy creation failed: hnsCall failed in Win32: The provided policy configuration is invalid or missing parameters. (0x803b000d)
E0526 10:59:37.064582    5020 proxier.go:1018] Endpoint information not available for service kaltura/phoenix:https. Not applying any policy
E0526 10:59:38.433836    4392 kubelet_network.go:102] Failed to ensure that nat chain KUBE-MARK-DROP exists: error creating chain "KUBE-MARK-DROP": executable file not found in %PATH%: 
E0526 10:59:39.362013    4392 helpers.go:735] eviction manager: failed to construct signal: "allocatableMemory.available" error: system container "pods" not found in metrics
W0526 10:59:39.362013    4392 helpers.go:808] eviction manager: no observation found for eviction signal nodefs.inodesFree
E0526 10:59:48.965710    4392 cni.go:280] Error deleting network: failed to parse Kubernetes args: pod does not have label vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address
E0526 10:59:48.965710    4392 remote_runtime.go:115] StopPodSandbox "04961285217a628c589467359f6ff6335355c73fdd61f3c975215105a6c307f6" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod "phoenix-57b76c578c-cczs2_kaltura" network: failed to parse Kubernetes args: pod does not have label vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address
E0526 10:59:48.965710    4392 kuberuntime_manager.go:799] Failed to stop sandbox {"docker" "04961285217a628c589467359f6ff6335355c73fdd61f3c975215105a6c307f6"}
E0526 10:59:48.965710    4392 kuberuntime_manager.go:594] killPodWithSyncResult failed: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "b35e92cc-7fa2-11e9-b07b-0ac0c740dc70" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"phoenix-57b76c578c-cczs2_kaltura\" network: failed to parse Kubernetes args: pod does not have label vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address"
E0526 10:59:48.965710    4392 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod b35e92cc-7fa2-11e9-b07b-0ac0c740dc70 ("phoenix-57b76c578c-cczs2_kaltura(b35e92cc-7fa2-11e9-b07b-0ac0c740dc70)"), skipping: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "b35e92cc-7fa2-11e9-b07b-0ac0c740dc70" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"phoenix-57b76c578c-cczs2_kaltura\" network: failed to parse Kubernetes args: pod does not have label vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address"
E0526 10:59:49.368785    4392 helpers.go:735] eviction manager: failed to construct signal: "allocatableMemory.available" error: system container "pods" not found in metrics
W0526 10:59:49.368785    4392 helpers.go:808] eviction manager: no observation found for eviction signal nodefs.inodesFree
```

kubectl -n kaltura describe pods phoenix-695b5bdff8-zzbq6

```
Name:               phoenix-695b5bdff8-zzbq6
Namespace:          kaltura
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               ip-10-10-12-97.us-east-2.compute.internal/10.10.12.97
Start Time:         Tue, 28 May 2019 12:30:48 +0300
Labels:             app.kubernetes.io/instance=kaltura-core
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=phoenix
                    pod-template-hash=2516168994
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/phoenix-695b5bdff8
Containers:
  kaltura:
    Container ID:
    Image:          <my-account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/vfd1-phoenix:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:           8040/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:80/tvp_api delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:80/tvp_api delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      TCM_SECTION:  kaltura-core
      TCM_URL:      https://10.10.12.99
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-jdd98 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-jdd98:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-jdd98
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                 beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows
                 kaltura.role=api
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                      From                                                Message
  ----    ------          ----                     ----                                                -------
  Normal  SandboxChanged  113s (x1707 over 7h27m)  kubelet, ip-10-10-12-97.us-east-2.compute.internal  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

Deployment yaml (from helm):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: phoenix
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: phoenix
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
      name: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: phoenix
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}


---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phoenix
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: phoenix
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: phoenix
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: phoenix
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.env.repository }}/{{ .Values.env.tag }}-phoenix:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: TCM_SECTION
              value: {{ .Values.env.tag }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8040
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /tvp_api
              port: 80
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /tvp_api
              port: 80
      strategy:
        type: RollingUpdate
        maxUnavailable: 1
      nodeSelector:
        kaltura.role: api
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: windows
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
```

Additionally to this pod I have an nginx pod running on linux nodes, that pod is load-balanced using aws-alb-ingress-controller.

Comment: Can you provide output of `kubectl describe pods <windows_pod_name>`, and post the `.yaml`?

Comment: All info provided

Comment: have you tried running first the [windows-server-iis.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/containers-roadmap/master/preview-programs/eks-windows-preview/windows-server-IIS.yaml) to see if cluster if correctly setup? If this fails as well go over [Amazon EKS Windows Preview Program](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/tree/master/preview-programs/eks-windows-preview#amazon-eks-windows-preview-program).

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
Apparently the vpc admission webhook was defined on the default namespace while my deployment of windows pods was on a different namespace.

Comment: Glad to see your issue was resolved. Please note VPC Admission webhook is no longer needed and has been deprecated. To enable windows support, enable IPAM by configuring as described in this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/windows-support.html#enable-windows-support.